# How to fetch csv file and show in shortcode

Tags: google, csv

I am missing a simple method to fetch data (every 30 minute) from a public Google Sheet CSV file and show the data with a shortcode in WordPress - can I do that with a php snippet in functions.php and how?

The data is actually just a dynamic number in a single cell.

Comment: Yes you can. I would look into WordPress shortcodes to output your data.

Comment: You'll need to 1) work out how to read the value using the Google Sheets API; 2) set up a scheduled job that fetches the value every 30 minutes and saves it in a transient; 3) read the transient in a shortcode or your page template to display it on the page

Comment: You could also read the value on demand in some circumstances e.g. if the transient has expired then have the current page load do it, but you'd have to worry about more than one thread doing that simultaneously. But on the other hand that would avoid background updates when no-one's viewing the page. So it's a trade-off with complexity vs extra unnecessary API accesses / server loads, so up to you.

Comment: I'm not sure anything is "simple" here.

Comment: What part do you need help with? The process for creating shortcodes is [very well documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/shortcode/), and parsing a CSV and outputting it is a pure PHP problem, so not specifically related to WordPress. If you need help with the latter then stackoverflow.com would be the place to ask.

Comment: @JacobPeattie - you're right. But I was hoping for that there was a Wordpress plugin for this feature. I can pretty much do this with Tablepress with auto update but I don't think that is a lightweight solution. I need the external value data to be outputted in a Wordpress primary menu.

Comment: Well you didn’t ask for a plugin, you asked for code. Plugin recommendations are off topic though, so this wouldn’t be the place to ask if that’s what you’re after.